# Creating multiple labels and adding text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label

I have a List of `KeyValuePair`s where the number of `KeyValuePair`s changes over time. In a form I need to create a label for each `KeyValuePair` that contains the `Value` as the text.

How can I do this?

This is what I have tried...

```
 For Each element In keyvalueP
            Dim Label1 As New Label
            With Label1
                .Width = 512
                .Height = 18
                .Left = 12
                .Text = " Nr. " & i & " - Matchtype " & element.Value.ToString
            End With
            i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Could you share some code, so we can see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I actually manage to find a solution that worked

```
Private Sub R75Dialog_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim labelText = ""
       Dim i = 0
       For Each element In keyvalueP
       labelText = " Nr. " & i & " Groupname:  " & element.Key.ToString & " - Matchtype " & element.Value.ToString
       Dim label As New Label()
       Dim count As Integer = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count
       label.Location = New Point(10, (25 * count) + 2)
       label.Size = New Size(1000, 20)
       label.Name = "label_" & (count + 1)
       label.Text = labelText
       Panel1.Controls.Add(label)
       i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```